# How to cache a variable with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, caching, flask-caching

I am building a web form using Flask and would like the user to be able to enter multiple entries, and give them the opportunity to regret an entry with an undo button, before sending the data to the database. I am trying to use [Flask-Caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but have not managed to set it up properly.

I have followed [The Flask Mega-Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) for setting up Flask (this is my first Flask app).

```
+---app
|   |   forms.py
|   |   routes.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   +---static
|   +---templates
```

I wonder how I need to configure the Flask app to basically be able to do the following things:

```
cache.add("variable_name", variable_data)
variable_name = cache.get("variable_name")
cache.clear()
```

in one of the pages (functions with @app.route decorators)?

In app.**init**.py I have:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_caching import Cache

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})

from app import routes
```

In routes.py I have:

```
from flask import current_app
```

and I use code below when I try to call the cache.

```
current_app.cache.add("variable_name", variable_data)
```

What I get when trying to use the form is the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'cache'
```

Pretty much all tutorials I've found have simply had the app declaration and all the routes in the same module. But how do I access the cache when I have the routes in another module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 1. Client Side Caching (built-in)

- All session data stored on client-side as Cookies.

**Example storing explicitly variable: `username`**

```
from flask import Flask, session, request 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "any random string"

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        session["username"] = request.form["username"]
    # to get value use session["username"]
```

### 2. Server Side Caching - ([Flask-Caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package)

- All data stored on server-side. Only one cookie key per client.
- [Recommended approach by the Flask team.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/caching/)

**Example storing explicitly variable: `username`**

```
from flask import Flask, request 
from flask_caching import Cache

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "any random string"
app.config["CACHE_TYPE"] = "SimpleCache" # better not use this type w. gunicorn
cache = Cache(app)

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        cache.set("username", request.form["username"])
    # to get value use cache.get("username")
```

In case of a multithread server with gunicorn I just tested that the best approach is `['CACHE_TYPE'] = 'FileSystemCache'` take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69903128/1207193).

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the `cache` object in `routes.py`, you have to import it first (from where you created it, i.e. `app/__init__.py`):

```
from app import cache
```

Then use it:

```
cache.add("variable_name", variable_data)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Didn't think of this solution as it's cyclical and for some reason I thought that the app would somehow be more "self-aware", especially with 'import current_app'.

Answer (score 1):

After piecing together a lot of bits from all over the Internet, I finally got this solution for **explicitly caching data with Flask-Caching in an app built with an application factory function**. The layout and application factory setup follow the Flask tutorial.

*(In my specific use case, I'm using the Google Calendar API and wanted to cache the service built to connect and authenticate as well as results from the queries. No need to re-query every time the user interacts with the page.)*

An abbreviated view of my flask app:

```
/.../mysite/
|--- mysite_flask/
|    |--- __init__.py   (application factory)
|    |--- cache.py      (for the flask_caching extension)
|    |--- site.py       (a blueprint, views, and related functions)
```

__init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure app as desired
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        ...
    )

    # check whether testing and for instance folder
    ...

    # importing and initializing other blueprints and views
    ...

    # import site blueprint, views, and functionality
    from . import site
    app.register_blueprint(site.bp)
    app.add_url_rule('/', endpoint='index')

    # Extensions
    # import cache functionality
    from .cache import cache
    cache.init_app(app)

    return app
```

cache.py

```
from flask_caching import Cache
cache = Cache(config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'SimpleCache'})
```

site.py

```
# Other required imports
...
from .cache import cache

bp = Blueprint('site', __name__)

# other views and functions
...

@bp.route('/book', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def book():
    # Connect to calendar or fail gracefully
    service = cache.get("service") # now the cache is available within a view
    if service is None: # service hasn't been added to cache or is expired
        try: # rebuild the service to connect to calendar
            service = connectToCalendar() # uses google.oauth2 and googleapiclient.discovery
            cache.set("service", service) # store service in cache
            g.error = False
        except Exception as e:
            flash(e)
            g.error = True
            return render_template('site/book.html') # jinja2 template that checks for g.error

    # remaining logic for the 'book' view
    ...

    # Cache results of queries
    if cache.get("week_{}".format(offset)) is None:
        # get new results
        week = getWeek(service)
        cache.set("week_{}".format(offset), week)
    else:
        week = cache.get("week_{}".format(offset))

    return render_template('site/book.html', <...arguments...>)
```