# GitHub-Flask Authorize Scope Issue

Tags: python, github, flask, github-api

I'm using [Github-Flask](https://github-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to authenitcate users on my app. I use `github.authorize(scope='user:email')`. How can I get the logged in user's email?

```
github = GitHub(app)
user = None

@app.route('/login')
def login():
   if user.username: 
      return redirect(url_for('index'))

   return github.authorize(scope='user:email')

@github.access_token_getter
def token_getter():
   if user is not None:
      return user.github_access_token

@app.route('/github-callback')
@github.authorized_handler
def authorized(oauth_token):
    if oauth_token is None:
       flask.flash("Authorization failed.")
       return redirect(url_for('index'))

   global user
   user.username = oauth_token
   return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `login` route is only redirecting to GitHub's authorization page, it has no way to access the user data yet because the user isn't logged in. Once you get to the `authorized` callback, you can make API calls to GitHub.

In the `authorized` route, use [`github.get`](https://github-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#invoking-remote-methods) to call the [`user`](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user) API endpoint.

```
data = github.get('user')
email = data['email']
```

---

Also, do not use `global user` to store the logged in user. See [Are global variables thread safe in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask) Instead, store the user id in `session`, and load the user into `g`, as shown in [GitHub-Flask's full example](https://github.com/cenkalti/github-flask/blob/master/example.py).