# Loading Python joblib package and sharing it in Flask between WSGI (Phusion Passenger) workers

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

I have a pre-trained [Gensim Word2Vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) model that I use as a global variable in a Flask web app:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
engine = gensim.Models.load("search_engine") # Python Class instance

@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
def api():
    query = requests.args("query", "")

    # dummy example: output the n closest words from the query in a JSON response.
    closest = json.dumps(engine.wv.most_similar(query))

    return app.response_class(
       response=closest,
       status=200,
       mimetype='application/json')
```

The model is quite heavy and rather slow to load in memory. Once it's loaded, due to internal Numpy matrix representation, it runs quite fast, and is used read-only.

Problem is, the Flask app runs on Phusion Passenger WSGI server, into CPanel, which spawns an arbitrary number of processes depending on requests. I have no control on the number of processes given it's a shared hosting.

Not only does that make the server hit its I/O limit, but loading the joblib object into memory for newly-spawned processes is actually slower than simply queuing new jobs and waiting for current processes to finish.

I would like to have the `engine` object shared in memory between workers. So far I tried:

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57810915/7087604) (`multiprocessing.managers`: `BaseManager`, `DictProxy`), but setting the Python object into `shared_dict["array"]` doesn't seem to take and the value stays `None` (apparently works only for strings and numbers),
- using `from flask_caching import Cache` and `cache.set("engine", gensim.Models.load("search_engine"))`, but then again `cache.get("engine")` fails with `redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 104 while writing to socket. Connection reset by peer.` and I'm guessing it is because Redis does not allow that much memory.

I really want to avoid using databases here because anyway, the expensive part is to load the Numpy matrices into memory and, once they are loaded, everything runs suprisingly fast considering it's a shared hosting designed for WordPress blogs (mostly).

Note that Word2Vec uses pickle archives to load previously-trained models, I actually use a child class saving to joblib archives for better compression (which, of course, adds to the reading issue here).

Comment: the solution with `multiprocessing.managers` is the correct approach, you have a bug in your not shown code, also you may want to use something like [Dask](https://www.dask.org/) or [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) to limit the number of computing workers if you care more about CPU efficiency than latency, you can have 1 computing worker and 10 html serving workers which costs much less resources than 10 computing workers.

Comment: with `flask_caching`, why you dont use `MemcachedCache` to use ram of pod, it fast and avoid I/O network with redis. It also good with you scale many worker by gunicorn

Comment: I am stuck with Phusion Passenger as a WSGI server and I can't control how workers are launched (nor how many). Basically, it does "lazy" worker spawning, meaning each worker restarts the app entirely within its own context (from what I understood). Following [this tuto](https://medium.com/@jgleeee/sharing-data-across-workers-in-a-gunicorn-flask-application-2ad698591875) shows that each `Manager().dict()` from each worker has its own memory address.