# Keeping a pyodbc connection in a global in Flask - is it safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, pyodbc

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214967/concurrency-safe-way-to-initialize-global-data-connections-in-flask) answers much of what I want to ask on a general level, but seems to suggest it's also *possible* to put connections in a global if done correctly. I would like to ask if my particular assumptions about using pyodbc in this manner are correct.

In my case the connection is read-only, and there are never more than one query open at a time in a request. Given these constraints, is it safe to keep a pyodbc connection persistent in a global? The way I do it currently is this.

All queries goes trough a function `db_execute()`
This looks for a global class member `glb.cnxn` and opens it if `None`.
It then does `cur = glb.cnxn.cursor()` and `cur.execute()` returning the result.
The cursor is only used to get column names and never reused.

Is this safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record:

The danger with this approach is that a long running query will block `glb.cnxn` from use by other requests. So a second user that requests a page will have to wait for the first users query to finish.

The answer in the linked post using the `g` "request global" works much better.