# How does Context Locals and The Request Context work together?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I am trying to learn to make a variable available across method through a decorator function in Flask.

I read [Flask request context documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/) and wrote the following code, which works as intended.

`a.py`

```
_request_ctx_stack.top.current_identity = payload.get('sub')
```

`b.py`

```
current_identity = getattr(_request_ctx_stack.top, 'current_identity', None)
```

However [flask-jwt](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-jwt) solves this problem by introducing an additional `local proxy` like this:

`a.py`

```
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy

current_identity = LocalProxy(lambda: getattr(_request_ctx_stack.top, 'current_identity', None))
_request_ctx_stack.top.current_identity = payload.get('sub')
```

`b.py`

```
from a import current_identity
```

Why? I read [werkzeug context locals documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/local/) and doesn't Flask already implements Werkzeug context locals for request object?

Is there any advantage of introducing `LocalProxy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LocalProxy` wraps the manual code you wrote for getting the value. Instead of needing that manual code everywhere you want to access `current_identity`, you access it as a proxy and it does the manual code for you.

It's most useful in libraries, where users wouldn't be expected to know how `current_identity` is set up, and would import the proxy to access it. The same applies to Flask itself: you're not expected to know how the request is set up, or where exactly it's stored, only that you access it by importing `request`.

A proxy is useful for data that is set up during and local to each request. If you used a true global variable, it would not behave the way you expect when multiple requests are being handled. See [Are global variables thread safe in flask? How do I share data between requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask-how-do-i-share-data-between-requests)