# Flask, re-read YAML outside of app.route scope from inside app.route

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to code a Flask application which reads the prefs file from disc and also allows down- and upload of that file.

But after uploading, the reload of the file inside the application makes the problem.

Loading at program start works fine as I am doing the following:

```
prefsfile=os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'foo.yaml')

def read_prefs():
    with open(prefsfile, 'r') as file:
        p=yaml.safe_load(file)
    return p

prefs=read_prefs()
```

Then I have some app.routes who access the prefs object like this, which works fine.

```
@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    items=prefs['foo']['items']
    messages=prefs['messages']
    return render_template(
        'foo.html',
        items = items,
        messages = messages
    )
```

Then I alter the object from inside an app.route and save it also to disc.

```
def save_prefs():
    with open(prefsfile, 'w') as file:
        yaml.dump(prefs, file)

@app.route('/foo/del_item', methods = ['POST'])
def foo_del_item():
    prefs['foo']['items'].pop(request.form['item_id'])
    save_prefs()
    return redirect(url_for('foo'))
```

BUT, when I upload the file from a form, then I do not know how to reload the prefs=read_prefs() outside an app.route to make it accessible for all other routes.

```
...
   file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
...
```

I tried:

```
@app.route('/reload_foo')
def reload_foo():
    prefs = read_prefs()

    return redirect(url_for('foo'))
```

But this works only inside the app.route not for all of them.

The goal is to reload the prefs=read_prefs() outside an app.route to make it accessible for all other app.routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables, even used with the syntax shown below, will not work as you expect in Flask, as multiple requests might try to modify them simultaneously. See [Are global variables thread safe in flask? How do I share data between requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask-how-do-i-share-data-between-requests) for correct ways to handle global data in web applications.

---

`prefs` is a global variable. If you want to change it inside a function, you need to used the [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) keyword:

```py
@app.route('/reload_foo')
def reload_foo():
    global prefs
    prefs = read_prefs()
    return redirect(url_for('foo'))
```

See ["What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?"](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) in the documentation.