# When flask application is configured to run on multiple processes, then is session shared across processes?

Tags: python, flask

I am referring to the answer from this post, where it is proposed that sessions can be used to store global state per-user: [Are global variables thread safe in flask? How do I share data between requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask-how-do-i-share-data-between-requests)

Specifically about sessions, when flask application is configured to run on multiple processes, then is session shared across processes?

Example: If 1 URL request hits process A, and the next request from the same user hits process B, then will the session set when the request hit process A be available in the process B?

Comment: You are scaring me as well... Isn't it literally multi-**process**es? not multi-**thread**s?

Comment: That question is about across threads. But I am asking about across process. Is it duplicate?

Comment: Good point, but the answer shares the relevance of the cookie-based session data where by default, session is stored client-side and isn't affected by underlying server configuration. See (possible) answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the request context is specific to a worker, which can be a thread/process/coroutine, means session is not shared and is set per request:

The [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/):

> Because a worker (thread, process, or coroutine depending on the server) handles only one request at a time, the request data can be considered global to that worker during that request. Flask uses the term context local for this.

Comment: That goes against the concept of sessions that we have known. As I expect it to be shared for all requests for the user. Atleast within the same process. And hopefully across processes. What you have mentioned - per request - are the objects like g, current_app, request.

Comment: My interpretation is that at the server level, each request is it's own worker, which has it's own process. Each request is (what I assume) sent with the session data and that data becomes global for that worker. In the doc I linked the "Lifetime of the context" gives a bit more detail, but there is still some missing detail which would answer your question directly.