# Does the use of global variables in a flask application which handles concurrent requests creates any issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, rest, flask

Does the use of global variables in a flask application which handles concurrent  requests at the same time creates any issue?

Comment: Yes, the global variables will be shared across user sessions and thus create race condition if used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are global variables thread safe in flask? How do I share data between requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask-how-do-i-share-data-between-requests)

Comment: More specifically, *unguarded access* to the globals can cause race conditions.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid such race conditions?

Comment: @chepner even guarded globals can lead to race condition-type scenarios when using workers e.g. user connects to a worker, global is updated, next request the user connects to an other worker where the global is not updated or a completely different value

Comment: @Masklinn Good point, though in my (possibly oversimplified) mental model, assigning a request to a worker without considering the consistency of the workers is an example of unguarded access.

Comment: @chepner fair enough

Answer (score 0):

Depends how the globals are used. If they're constants, it doesn't matter. If they're actual variables (mutable objects or values which get set) however you can have

- incoherent states when using multithreaded server
- information leaks when using multithreaded server (one user seeing data from a different user)
- partially-visible changes and rollbacking changes when using multiprocessing servers (e.g. gunicorn workers) as the global would be updated on a per-worker basis, and users can "jump" from worker to worker

Why do you want to have globals, exactly?