# How to use variable from one request in another request test body in postman test body?

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I want to execute 3 requests (api1, api2 and api3) one after the other. I want to make api3 request dependent on values(type:int) of api1 and api2.

In api1 request test body:

```
var data = pm.response.json();
var count1 = data.length;
```

In api2 request test body:

```
var data = pm.response.json();
var count2 = data.length;
if(count1 == 0 && count2 == 0){
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```

Doing this, it throws a `"ReferenceError: count1 is not defined"` after firing the api2 request.

I don't want to execute the request api3 if both the count values (count1 and count2) are 0.
Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are global variables thread safe in flask? How do I share data between requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask-how-do-i-share-data-between-requests)

Comment: Nope.. I need the syntax to use variable from one request into the other request in the postman app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the test of the api1 request, you need to store the value of count1 in an environment variable: `pm.environment.set("count1", count1));`

Then use that environment variable in the test of api2: `count1 = pm.environment.get("count1");`

Comment: Would you then please be so kind to upvote and accept the answer? Thank you!

Comment: Sure I tried.. It popped me "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Kindly upvote my question so that I can increase my reputation and upvote your answer later.. :)

Comment: It shouldn't stop you accepting Christian's answer though.

Comment: Done @DannyDainton. I have also upvoted the answer :)