# How exactly do dynos/memory/processes work?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

For anyone who has used Heroku (and perhaps anyone else who has deployed to an PaaS before and has experience):

I'm confused on what Heroku means by "dynos", how dynos handle memory, and how users scale. I read that they define dynos as "app containers", which means that the memory/file system of dyno1 can't be accessed by dyno2. Makes sense in theory.

> The containers used at Heroku are called “dynos.” Dynos are isolated, virtualized Linux containers that are designed to execute code based on a user-specified command. (https://www.heroku.com/dynos)

Also, users can define how many dynos, or "app containers", are instantiated, if i understand correctly, through commands like `heroku ps:scale web=1`, etc etc.

I recently created a webapp (a Flask/gunicorn app, if that even matters), where I declare a variable that keeps track of how many users visited a certain route (I know, not the best approach, but irrelevant anyways). In local testing, it appeared to be working properly (even for multiple clients)

When I deployed to Heroku, with only a single web dyno (`heroku ps:scale web=1`), I found this was not the case, and that the variable appeared to have multiple instances and updated differently. I understand that memory isn't shared between different dynos, but I have only one dyno which runs the server. So I thought that there should only be a single instance of this variable/web app? Is the dyno running my server on single/multiple processes? If so, how can I limit it?

Note, this web app does save files on disk, and through each API request, I check to see if the file does exist. Because it does, this tells me that I am requesting from the same dyno.

Perhaps someone can enlighten me? I'm a beginner to deployment, but willing to learn/understand more!

Comment: You're asking a bunch of things here, but I'll suggest a relevant dupe for part of this. In general, though, [please limit yourself to one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627).

Comment: Actually, there's probably enough for an answer here. I'll add one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the dyno running my server on single/multiple processes?

[Yes, probably](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#basic-configuration):

> Gunicorn forks multiple system processes within each dyno to allow a Python app to support multiple concurrent requests without requiring them to be thread-safe. In Gunicorn terminology, these are referred to as worker processes (not to be confused with Heroku worker processes, which run in their own dynos).

> We recommend setting a configuration variable for this setting. Gunicorn automatically honors the WEB_CONCURRENCY environment variable, if set.
>
> ```
> heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=3
> ```
>
> The `WEB_CONCURRENCY` environment variable is automatically set by Heroku, based on the processes’ Dyno size. This feature is intended to be a sane starting point for your application. We recommend knowing the memory requirements of your processes and setting this configuration variable accordingly.

The solution isn't to limit your processes, but to fix your application. [Global variables shouldn't be used to store data across processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32815451/354577). Instead, store data in [a database or in-memory data store](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores).

> Note, this web app does save files on disk, and through each API request, I check to see if the file does exist. Because it does, this tells me that I am requesting from the same dyno.

If you're just trying to check which dyno you're on, fine. But you probably don't want to be saving actual data to the dyno's filesystem because it [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). You'll lose all changes made to the filesystem whenever your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).