# Variable value not being updated with multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, thread-safety

Hi I'm currently developing a web app whereby my flask backend deals with prediction models and my sveltekit frontend retrieves the predicted data from the backend. As my backend uses data that is constantly updated, I have scheduled a job every week to retrain the data. When my backend starts running, it first trains the model on a separate thread, and retraining also takes place on this separate thread. The main thread handles the api calls. Initially the variable `model` is set to `None`, only after it's initialised and trained, then it points to a model. At least that's what im trying to acheive. However, even after the model is trained, the variable `model` is still found to be `None`, as my frontend is getting the response: `Error: Model not setup`, when I call the `http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict` endpoint. **I tried using threading.Lock() to prevent race conditions but I'm still getting the same error.** I've reduced my code to be as minimal as possible (with simple print statements). These are my flask backend files:

my app.py:

```
import threading

from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

import models
from routes import routes

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.register_blueprint(routes)


def setup_model():
    models.setup()


# set the flag for setting up the model
setup_model_flag = True

if setup_model_flag:
    training_thread = threading.Thread(target=setup_model)
    training_thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

my models.py:

```
# setup
import threading
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

from schedule import every
from schedule import repeat
from schedule import run_pending

model_lock = threading.Lock()
model = None


def prepare_data():
    return "preparing data"


class LSTMModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_trained = False

        self.df = prepare_data()

        self.train()

    def train(self):
        print("Training model...")

        self.is_trained = True

    def predict(self, num_months):
        print("Predicting...")


def setup():
    with model_lock:
        print("Initializing...")
        global model
        model = LSTMModel()
        print(f"Model trained on {datetime.now()}")

    # schedule the job to run every sunday
    @repeat(every().sunday)
    def job():
        with model_lock:
            # update model and retrain data
            print("Initializing new model...")
            global model
            # initialize new instance of model
            model = LSTMModel()
            print(f"Model trained on {datetime.now()}")

    while True:
        # print(idle_seconds())
        run_pending()
        sleep(1)
```

my routes.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request

from models import model, model_lock

routes = Blueprint('routes', __name__)


@routes.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()  # Parse JSON data from the request body
        print('Received data:', data)

        input_data = data['value']
        selected_option = data['type']

        # Log a message to indicate that the endpoint is called
        print('Prediction endpoint called. Input:', input_data, 'Type:', selected_option)

    except Exception as e:
        # An error occurred, return an error response with 400 status code
        return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid JSON format'}), 400

    if selected_option == 'Years':
        num_months = int(input_data) * 12
    else:
        num_months = int(input_data)

    with model_lock:
        if model is None:
            # Model is not setup, return an error response with 500 status code
            return jsonify({'error': 'Model not setup'}), 500

        if not model.is_trained:
            # Model is not trained, return an error response with 500 status code
            return jsonify({'error': 'Model not trained'}), 500

        else:
            try:
                # Perform prediction using the model
                prediction = model.predict(num_months)
            except Exception as e:
                # An error occurred during prediction, return an error response with 500 status code
                return jsonify({'error': 'Prediction error: {}'.format(str(e))}), 500

    # Return the prediction as a JSON response
    return jsonify({'prediction': prediction})
```

Calling the api can be done with postman with the body in this json format:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to share `model` between threads. This is fighting against how Flask is designed and I wouldn't recommend it. If we need to share state between requests/threads we should consider using an external source like a database to store and retrieve that data.

If you want a quick and dirty solution you could also try using a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) or the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module to pickle in and out your desired state. [Flask caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is another potentially good alternative depending on your use case.

[A better explanation than I've given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask-how-do-i-share-data-between-requests)

Comment: Thankss! I used flask cache with redis, works well!