werkzeug Local got unexpected value
I may have a misunderstood with werkzeug.local
Here is my simplified test code:
from flask import Flask, request
from werkzeug.local import Local
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)

local_data = Local()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if local_data.data:
         # I don't know why new request without token will get token and return here.
         return local_data.data
    local_data.data = request.headers.get('token')
    return local_data.data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

In fact, my logic is that when a request arrives, it first performs a get. If it doesn't retrieve a value from local_data.data, it sets a token to local_data.data and returns it. However, I noticed that under concurrent conditions, a new request coming in would get content it shouldn't have access to.
I expect that only the first request will carry a token, and other requests should return None because there are nothing in their local thread.
However, in continuous observations, I found that many requests successfully retrieved the value stored in the local_data.data, which means local_data is not working here.
I don't know why, and GPT says my code should have no mistakes...

Global variables are not thread-safe in Flask, and the life-cycle of Werkzeug worker (i.e., request handler process) isn't deterministic.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask-how-do-i-share-data-between-requests discusses the exact issue, with different approaches to handle "session-specific" data.

@DeepakD The issue of thread safety arises when the frontend requests my interface. In principle, when using Local(), each request should not retrieve any content the first time local_data.data is called. However, this phenomenon consistently reproduces in one of the interfaces in my test environment, with the triggered interface and timing being exactly the same each time. Initially, I suspected that the Local() object is thread-unsafe in Flask, leading to a problem with a specific worker during load balancing after a certain number of requests due to Gunicorn's worker.

After changing the number of Gunicorn workers, I found that the issue is unrelated to the number of Gunicorn workers.Meanwhile, in both the production and development environments, with the same code and after adding logging at the relevant code points, the issue could not be reproduced even after more than one million requests over two weeks of stable operation. However, in the test environment, it consistently results in a blocking exception. This is the point that puzzles me.
